# App crashed when try to display dialog box

Tags: java, android, crash, dialog

Just a simple things, the app should shows dialog box when button is clicked. But when it is clicked, it crashed. And I don't understand what are the `logCat` error trying to said.

```
 addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplication());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_box);
                dialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog View");
                Button btnExit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
                btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnChoosePath)
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                               // activeGallery();
                            }
                        });
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto)
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                                //activeTakePhoto();
                            }
                        });

                // show dialog on screen
                dialog.show();
            }

            });
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:onClick="btnChoosePathClicked"
        android:id="@+id/btnChoosePath"
        android:background="@color/honey_dew2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:text="From Gallery"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="btnTakePhotoClicked"
        android:id="@+id/btnTakePhoto"
        android:background="@color/honey_dew2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnChoosePath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:text="Take Photo"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="btnExitClicked"
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:background="@color/honey_dew2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnTakePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:text="Exit"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**LogCat error**

```
12-09 17:57:34.344  18804-18804/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:698)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.AddMoreClaims$1.onClick(AddMoreClaims.java:68)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4230)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17660)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
```

where `(AddMoreClaims.java:68)` refer to   `dialog.show();`. What's wrong here ?

Comment: Your using `Activity` or `Fragment`??

Comment: @Clairvoyant Activity

Comment: Don't use `getApplication()` in dialog. Use `your_activity.this` for Activity and `getActivity()` for Fragment.

Comment: @oberflansch thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `dialog` declaration like below code:

**For Activity:**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Your_Activity_Name.this);
```

**For Fragment:**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
```

Comment: Thanks !! I just follow the tutorial without realizing it is `fragment` not `activity` lol

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Because `getApplication()` retuning `null`.

Use `v.getContext()` or `ActivityName.this` to create `Dialog` object:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
OR
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create Dialog with an application Context, you should use Activity Context.

```
new Dialog(MyActivity.this); //if you use Activity
new Dialog(getActivity()); //if you use Fragment
```

Answer (score 1):

You should show your dialog inside activity and never in application.
Open your dialog in your current open activity and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated above your Context i.e. `getApplication()` is wrong.

This is because you need to have the current `Activity`'s `context` to display anything (popup, view, dialog) over it.

Whereas you could have a `getApplicationContext()` to start a new Activity, you will have to use `this` (inside an Activity) or `getActivity()` inside a Fragment.

Here's more info on [Context and which one to use and when](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)

Comment: can you explain [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125541/why-the-selected-item-in-spinner-doesnt-display-on-edittext) ?